# Typo in Elementary Geometry from an Advanced Standpoint?

Tags: geometry

In the book **Elementary Geometry from an Advanced Standpoint** by Edwin E. Moise, Page 78-79, Theorem 6 states that

> **Theorem 6**, *Page 78-79*. If $F$ is in the interior of $\angle BAC$, then $\overrightarrow{AF}-F$ lies in the interior of $\angle BAC$.

*Proof:*

1. By definition of the interior of an angle, $F$ and $B$ are on the same side of $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$. By Theorem 3, $\overrightarrow{AF}-F$ lies on the side of $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ that contains $F$. Therefore $\overrightarrow{AF}-F$ lies on the side of $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ htat contains $B$.
2. By definition of the interior of an angle, $F$ and $B$ are on the same side of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$. By Theorem 3, $\overrightarrow{AF}-F$ lies on the side of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ that contains $F$. Therefore $\overrightarrow{AF}-F$ lies on the side of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ that contains $C$.
3. By (1) and (2), it follows that $\overrightarrow{AF}-F$ lies in the interior of $\angle BAC$. QED.

> **Theorem 3**, *Page 76-77*. Given a line, and a ray which has its end point on the line but does not lie on the line. Then all points of the ray, except for the end point, are on the same side.

First, it violates Theorem 3's requirement that ray $\overrightarrow{AF}$'s endpoint (which is $A$) does not lie in $\angle BAC$. Second, I fail to see why $F$ cannot be in the interior of $\angle BAC$ in the *then* clause of Theorem 6, after we just assumed it.

Is this a typo or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Without access to the book I can't see how this can  be answered because it depends on how exactly  Theorem 3 is used in the proof of Theorem 6. Perhaps you could supply details.

Comment: @MichaelCohen I was going to say exactly the same.

Comment: Agreed, I think that it is a typo; IMO it must be $\overrightarrow{AF}-A$ (see Figure 4.12).

Comment: @MichaelCohen Added the proof of Theorem 3.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA True. Though I have some doubts whether it's a typo or not since $\overrightarrow{AF}-F$ had been repeated throughout the proof. Might have been copy-paste though.